# Efficiently processing values in one array based on a ID value in another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2-d numpy array containing a series of values, and a matching array which identifies the group that the cell belongs to. I wish to run a few simple operations in the first array in each group. To illustrate, I might have a data and ID array that look something like this:

```
data = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
IDs = np.array([
    ["A", "A", "B"],
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["B", "C", "C"]
])
```

And I might want to take the mean and standard deviation for all A, B and C values, with an output that looks something like this:

```
[['A', 1.333333333333333, 1.247219128924647],
['B', 4.0, 1.6329931618554521],
['C', 6.666666666666667, 1.247219128924647]]
```

Right now, I solve this problem with the following code:

```
unique_IDs = np.unique(IDs)
results = []
for ID in unique_IDs:
    group_data = data[IDs == ID]
    mean = np.mean(group_data)
    stdev = np.std(group_data)
    results.append([ID, mean, stdev])
```

I think this is straightforward and comprehensible, but it's not very fast. When using my real data, arrays are generally ~200 mb (5,000 * 10,000 instead of 3 * 3), and there are hundreds of unique IDs. Each iteration takes a few seconds and the whole operation can take over a half hour.

My "gut instinct" is that this could be done faster if I didn't have to iterate over every unique ID value and repeat the lookup and operations, but I have no idea if that's actually true or how I would go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be doing a lot of these sorts of grouped operations I would highly recommend you take a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
IDs = np.array([["A", "A", "B"],
                ["A", "B", "C"],
                ["B", "C", "C"]])
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':IDs.ravel(), 'data':data.ravel()})
print(df)
#   ID  data
# 0  A     0
# 1  A     1
# 2  B     2
# 3  A     3
# 4  B     4
# 5  C     5
# 6  B     6
# 7  C     7
# 8  C     8

print(df.groupby('ID').agg([np.mean, np.std]))
#         data          
#         mean       std
# ID                    
# A   1.333333  1.527525
# B   4.000000  2.000000
# C   6.666667  1.527525
```

See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) for some more examples.

Comment: I find this approach to clear and straightforward, and it resulted in a 40X speedup when running a test with a 5000 * 5000 array and 500 unique IDs.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get numeric `IDs` corresponding to the string `IDs`. These numeric IDs would be useful both in `mean` and `std` calculations.

Now, for mean calculations, those numeric IDs could be used as `"weights"` for binning with [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html), giving us the sum of data elements corresponding to each `ID`. Next up. using the counts of elements for each ID, one can then get the mean values. Here's the implementation -

```
_,idx,counts = np.unique(IDs,return_inverse=True,return_counts=True)  
mean_vals = np.bincount(idx,data.ravel())/counts
```

For `std` calculations, one way would be to sort the IDs such that the identical IDs are placed consecutively. Then, re-arrange data to form another 2D array, such that all data elements corresponding to identical IDs are in same rows and the unfilled places are set as `NaNs`. The idea here is to perform `np.std` in a vectorized manner along the columns. There would be masking needed for places to be filled. Please note that this might be a memory hungry approach if there is an ID with a relatively higher count. The implementation would re-use `idx` and `counts` from the code earlier and would look something like this -

```
data_RO = np.empty((counts.size,counts.max()))
data_RO[:] = np.nan
data_RO[np.arange(counts.max()) < counts[:,None]] = data.ravel()[idx.argsort()]
std_vals = np.nanstd(data_RO,axis=1)
```

Sample run and verify output -

1) Inputs:

```
In [51]: data
Out[51]: 
array([[0, 1, 6],
       [2, 5, 0],
       [6, 3, 6]])

In [52]: IDs
Out[52]: 
array([['A', 'A', 'B'],
       ['A', 'B', 'C'],
       ['B', 'A', 'C']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

2) Output from code listed in the question:

```
In [53]: unique_IDs = np.unique(IDs)

In [54]: results = []

In [55]: for ID in unique_IDs:
   ....:         group_data = data[IDs == ID]
   ....:         mean = np.mean(group_data)
   ....:         stdev = np.std(group_data)
   ....:         results.append([ID, mean, stdev])
   ....:     

In [56]: results
Out[56]: 
[['A', 1.5, 1.1180339887498949],
 ['B', 5.666666666666667, 0.47140452079103168],
 ['C', 3.0, 3.0]]
```

3) Output from proposed solution:

```
In [57]: _,idx,counts = np.unique(IDs,return_inverse=True,return_counts=True) 

In [58]: np.bincount(idx,data.ravel())/counts
Out[58]: array([ 1.5       ,  5.66666667,  3.        ])

In [59]: data_RO = np.empty((counts.size,counts.max()))

In [60]: data_RO[:] = np.nan

In [61]: mask = np.arange(counts.max()) < counts[:,None]

In [62]: data_RO[mask] = data.ravel()[idx.argsort()]

In [63]: np.nanstd(data_RO,axis=1)
Out[63]: array([ 1.11803399,  0.47140452,  3.        ])
```

Comment: Your std approach (which could be generalized to other np functions) might be too memory intensive, as the IDs have the potential to be highly asymetrical. However, I'll give it a shot- if it turns out considerably faster than the other proposed solution, it might be worth it. Thanks!